# Appended later elements not remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I wrote below code to append 5 li when i click on add button but the problem is with remove button, when i click on remove button i want to remove last 5 recent lis . but it does not work.
here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".moree").click(function () {
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {              
      $(this)
        .prev()
        .append('<li style="display:none">Title 2</li>')
        .children()
        .last()
        .hide()
        .delay(delay)
        .slideDown(400);
      delay += 400;
    }
  });
  
    $(".remove").click(function () {
      $(this)
        .parents('ol').remove()
        .slideUp(400);
   
  });
  
});
```

```css
ol > li{ list-style:none; padding-top:10px; border:1px solid green;margin-top:10px;}
.moree{ width:30px; background:yellow;}.remove{ width:30px; background:red;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
      <ol>
        <li>title</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
      <div class="remove">Remove 5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ol` is not a parent of the `.remove` button. You need to amend your traversal logic slightly.

To get the last 5 elements, use `.slice(-5)`. Also, if you `remove()` the elements before you call `slideUp()` they will just vanish. You need to call `slideUp()` first. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".moree").click(function() {
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      $(this).prev().append('<li style="display: none">Title 2</li>').children().last().delay(delay).slideDown(400);
      delay += 400;
    }
  });

  $(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.content').find('ol li').slice(-5).slideUp(400, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ol > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.moree {
  width: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
.remove {
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <ol>
      <li>title</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
    <div class="remove">Remove 5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use `parents('div.content')` to find the main DIV and then it's `ol with li`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove',function () {
   $(this)
     .parents('div.content')  //Get the main div
     .find('ol > li:gt(0)')   //Find ol and li index greater then 0
     .slideUp(400,function(){ //Slide up with remove from DOM
         $(this).remove();  
      })
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".moree").click(function () {
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {              
      $(this)
        .prev()
        .append('<li style="display:none">Title 2</li>')
        .children()
        .last()
        .hide()
        .delay(delay)
        .slideDown(400);
      delay += 400;
    }
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', '.remove',function () {
      $(this)
        .parents('div.content')
        .find('ol > li:gt(0)')
        .slideUp(400,function(){
          $(this).remove();
      })
  });
  
});
```

```css
ol > li{ list-style:none; padding-top:10px; border:1px solid green;margin-top:10px;}
.moree{ width:30px; background:yellow;}.remove{ width:30px; background:red;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
      <ol>
        <li>title</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
      <div class="remove">Remove 5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse from parent node to required element and slice it by 3

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".moree").click(function () {
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {              
      $(this)
        .prev()
        .append('<li style="display:none">Title 2</li>')
        .children()
        .last()
        .hide()
        .delay(delay)
        .slideDown(400);
      delay += 400;
    }
  });
  
    $(".remove").click(function () {

    $('ol > li').slice(-3).remove();
  });
  
});
```

```css
ol > li{ list-style:none; padding-top:10px; border:1px solid green;margin-top:10px;}
.moree{ width:30px; background:yellow;}.remove{ width:30px; background:red;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
      <ol>
        <li>title</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="moree">Add 3</div>
      <div class="remove">Remove 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse from parent element to required element and then slice as per your your requirement. here is 5

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".moree").click(function () {
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {              
      $(this)
        .prev()
        .append('<li style="display:none">Title 2</li>')
        .children()
        .last()
        .hide()
        .delay(delay)
        .slideDown(400);
      delay += 400;
    }
  });
  
    $(".remove").click(function () {
 
      $(this).parent('.content').find('ol  li').slice(-5)
        .slideUp(400);
   
  });
  
});
```

```css
ol > li{ list-style:none; padding-top:10px; border:1px solid green;margin-top:10px;}
.moree{ width:30px; background:yellow;}.remove{ width:30px; background:red;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
      <ol>
        <li>title</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="moree">Add 5</div>
      <div class="remove">Remove 5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In that code have errror. if we add 2times totally 10li added. then click remove hide5. again click remove the last 5li not hided. check it.